# jQuery Selector Question

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i am actually doing a accordion/sliding menu. here, i want to slide up sibling li > ul that has been open (or displayed). can i simplify this further?

```
$(this).parent("li").siblings("li:has(ul)").children("ul").slideUp("fast");
```

i also noticed that i cannot skip the children() part and do something like

```
$(this).parent("li").siblings("li:has(ul) ul").slideUp("fast");
```

why is siblings("li:has(ul) ul") different from siblings("li:has(ul)").children("ul")?

Comment: `li:has(ul)` gets a list of all `<li>` and removes the `<li>`s that do not contain a `<ul>` from the list before returning it. So never do `li:has(ul) ul` because that just adds one extra operation without affecting the behavior.

Comment: hmm does it mean if i use :has() it must be the last operation? i can select a ul that is a child of a li, that has a ul?

Comment: Well you can use `:has()` anywhere you like, I'm just saying that using `li:has(ul) ul` is unnecessary since it's the same as `li ul`, except slower. You can do things like `li:has(ul) span` to only select `<span>` elements of `<li>` elements that have sublists, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are selecting the list elements that are siblings as long as those list elements have unordered lists as children, then you get the unordered list children.  In the second case you are looking for siblings that are unordered lists that are children (immediate or nested) of list elements.  The problem is that you are looking in the siblings of a list element which has no unordered list siblings (only list element siblings).

The key is that the selector in the siblings method is a filter.  It is only used to select out of the list of unique siblings, those siblings that match the criteria specified in the selector.  In your case, there aren't any siblings that do (can) match the criteria in the second case.

Example:

```
<ul>
     <li id='li0' class='selected'>
         <ul id='ul0' class='child'>
            ...
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li id='li1' class='sibling'>
        <ul id='ul1' class='child'>
           ...
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li id='li2' class='sibling'>
        <ul id='ul2' class='child'>
           <li id='li2_0' class='grandchild'>
              <ul id='ul2_0' class='greatgrandchild'>
                 ...
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='li3'>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`$('.selected').siblings('li:has(ul)')`  will return the collection of list elements with ids `li1` and `li2`.  `$('.selected').siblings('li:has(ul) ul') will return an empty set because it is the same as`$('.selected').siblings().filter('li:has(ul) ul').  Since siblings returns the set with ids `li1' and`li2`, these don't match the filter which selects the unordered list children of a list element (with unordered list children).

You can see the effect using the following snippet of code.

```
$(function() {
    dumpIds('siblings',$('.selected').siblings());
    dumpIds('filtered sibs',$('.selected').siblings('li:has(ul)'));
    dumpIds('ul filtered sibs',$('.selected').siblings('li:has(ul) ul'));
});

function dumpIds(title,elements) {
    var idset = '';
    var sep = '';
    elements.each( function() {
        idset = idset + sep + this.id;
        sep = ', ';
    });
    alert(title + ':' + idset);
}
```

Comment: wow i am still confused at this 1 ... i may need more help/time understanding this... "The problem is that you are looking in the siblings of a list element which has no unordered list siblings (only list element siblings)." ... why "no unordered list siblings" i thought "li:has(ul) ul" will get li's that have ul and get those ul's

Comment: Yes, but only if they are in the set of siblings of the list element -- which they are not.  They are children of the list element's siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Finds all the direct children of `<li>`s that have `<ul>` inside:

```
$("li:has(ul)").children("ul")

//or
$("li:has(ul) > ul")
```

Finds all the descendants of `<li>`s that have `<ul>` inside:

```
$("li:has(ul) ul")
```

Comment: The question was about why the siblings method works differently, no about how to do the selection.  In both cases it selects the unordered lists inside the list elements, though the latter would also select unordered lists at any depth, not just the immediate children.

Comment: Actually the question is: why is siblings("li:has(ul) ul") different from siblings("li:has(ul)").children("ul")? The siblings operator provides the context, but my point is that the "li ul" returns all ul *descendants" while .children returns direct children (like "li > ul"). It's a really common confusion as .parents returns all ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of the siblings selector. Think of it this way: it takes `$('li:has(ul) ul')` and `$(this).parent("li").siblings()` and returns a jQuery object populated with the intersection of the two. In other words, it's looking for unordered lists that are children of list items that have UL children that are siblings of `$(this).parent`.